# simple javascript with document.getElementById to extract text from html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping

I created a Safari extension, it's button, toolbar, I just want to do a very simple thing, nothing special, I want to click on this button, and the alert shows just that portion of text extracted with document.getElementById. The alert returns null.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let myElement = document.getElementById("p-interaction-label");
    alert("The element from the paragraph is: " + myElement);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ToolBar</button>
```

Thank you for your help :))))

Comment: Where is your element with id `p-interaction-label`?

Comment: There is some need for modern JS here: don't use `alert` (it blocks the JS thread, and should only be used in code written prior to 2010), use `console.log` instead. Also, don't use the ancient `onclick` attribute on the HTML side, use `addEventListener` on your JS side instead.

Comment: I'm using a button in the tool bar through Safari Extension, since I need that button. The id is in this page, I chose a random page to test the script: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciao

Comment: I would like that the button works on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `myElement` to an element instead of it's value/content. Change your variable assignment as follows:

If `p-interaction-label` is not an input field, you can use `textContent` like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    let myElement = document.getElementById("p-interaction-label").textContent;
    console.log(myElement);
    alert("The element from the paragraph is: " + myElement);
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2vhy7beu/11/

---

If `p-interaction-label` is an input field, you can use `value` like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    let myElement = document.getElementById("p-interaction-label").value;
    console.log(myElement);
    alert("The element from the paragraph is: " + myElement);
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2vhy7beu/7/

Comment: the code that I chose in wikipedia for my test is the following: <h3 id=“p-interaction-label”>Interaction</h3>, but you can choose another one if this can help me to understand. With none of those works:.textContent, .value, .innerHTML.

Comment: and I'm trying to extract that word "Interaction" from that wikipedia page using a button in my toolbar through Safari Extension, could be this the problem? I thought that the code could directly read on the current page and look for that ID

Comment: Hmmmm. I think your script is loading before the html has loaded so the function can't find the 'p-interaction-label' yet.

Comment: I run the script when I click on the button, I think there is something missing in my script, since it's a Safari extension. The code that you wrote above is more than correct and valid, but used in a console, I suppose that using a button in a toolbar requires something more, just I cannot manage to find it, but I'll keep you posted if I do.